# Mistake in Betti number computation

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth complex projective curve of genus $g$ and let $C^{(2)}$ be the symmetric product of $C$ with itself, i.e. the quotient of $C\times C$ by the involution $\sigma$  which exchanges the two coordinates. To compute the second Betti number of $C^{(2)}$ I am reasoning as follows.
First of all it should be $$H^2(C^{(2)}) = H^2(C\times C)^\sigma$$ (maybe here is the mistake?). Then, using Künneth theorem, it follows that 
$$\dim H^2(C\times C)^\sigma = 1 + \frac{2g(2g+1)}{2},$$ the first summand is the dimension of the diagonal of $H^2\otimes H^0\oplus H^0\otimes H^2$, while the second summand is the dimension of symmetric tensors in $H^1\otimes H^1$.

If $g=2$ the above formula gives dimension $11$. On the other hand in this case $C^{(2)}\to JC$, defined by $p+q\mapsto [p+q-K_C]$ is a birational morphism which contracts a unique excepcional divisor, the graph of the unique $g_2^1$ of $C$, so that the dimension is $1$ more than the second Betti number of $JC$ which should be $6$ (again by Künneth).

Could you please point out the mistake?

Comment: A quick, and ignorant comment - the involution  $\sigma$ fixes the diagonal, so does not act freely. An issue?

Comment: Would this imply $H^2(C^{(2)}) \subsetneq H^2(C\times C)^\sigma$?

Comment: I did say "ignorant" you know... But in any case equality seems problematic.  I'll try to think about it too, but I know that there are people here (including you!) who are more competent than I, and stand a good chance of being faster than I at figuring out  the answer. Maybe by looking at $H^2 ( C \times C \setminus D )$, where $D$ is the diagonal?

Comment: You might add an algebraic-topology tag, or riemann surfaces, or  maybe an complex manifolds tag, or... to attract the talent. If you do so, just to be safe, also add 'Riemann Surface = smooth  projective  complex curve' up front...

Comment: I might have missed  the point of your question (in the comment): is it clear that  $ H^2 ( C ^{(2)} ) \to H^2 ( C \times C )^\sigma$ is an injection?

Comment: I have just found this paper which seems to explain the situation: https://ac.els-cdn.com/0040938362900198/1-s2.0-0040938362900198-main.pdf?_tid=51a5624b-5bd8-4ee2-8350-ba63dae7003e&acdnat=1527388105_0ca7b9acdfe28adb3479eeaf22c516f0

Comment: It seems that the first equality is ok. The problem is with the second one, there are antisymmetric relations (like coming from a wedge product).

Comment: Certainly $H^2 ( J ) = \wedge^2 H^1 (J)$; so the dimension in the $g=2$ case is $6$.

Comment: Yes, so that the dimension $H^2(C^{(2)})$ is 7. Thank you for all the answers. I have almost got it, it seems that relations (2.3) are just the wedge product of forms.